# getJSON to update progress bar

Tags: javascript, css, json, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Trying to get this progress bar on Bootstrap to show real-time progress from a JSON API, while also showing the % of goal achieved:

Here is how it looks right now: http://puu.sh/jt2Gu/823f6a6a0f.png

Both progress bars should be centered on the page and the progress itself isnt updating and I'm not sure why, please help?

- progress bar for coins sold
- progress bar for amount raised
- % funded (should be on top of picture)

**CSS:**

```
}
.progress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="banner-buynow">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 object-non-visible"
        data-animation-effect="fadeIn">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=
            "opentac();">Buy Now<br>

            <div class="ratebtc"></div></a>
        </div>

        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar active progress-bar-striped active">
                <div class="percentage-label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class=
        "progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active"
        style="width:1%">
            <div class="goal-label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="funded-label"></div>
```

**JS**

```
 $.getJSON("https://www2.shapeshift.io/crowdsales", function (json) {
    var soldT = Math.round(json.sold);
    var left = json.remaining;
    var total = Math.round(soldT+left);
    var ratebtc = json.rateT;
    var percent = Math.round(soldT/total*100);
    var backers = json.orders;
    var raisedtotal = Math.round(json.raised) + ' BTC';
    var goal = Math.round(raisedtotal/730);
    var percentsold = Math.round(percent) + '%';
    var backers = json.orders + ' backers';
    var funded = Math.round(json.raised/730*100);
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentsold);
    $('.percentage-label').html(soldT + "  coins sold ");
    $('.ratebtc').html(ratebtc );  
    $('.backers').html(raisedtotal + " from " + backers );
    $('.progress-bar-success').css('width', goal);
    $('.goal-label').html(raisedtotal + " towards goal of 730 BTC");
    $('.funded-label').html(funded + " % funded");
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qy1ko5xf/

Comment: Going back to first principals, what are you getting back from the server for the percentsold and raisedtotal values? Are these correct at all?

Comment: I think you are trying to calculate `goal` by dividing a string. `raisedtotal` is not a number, since you are appending `' BTC'` to it.

Comment: server values are correct, numbers are accurate but the progress bar isnt updating - not sure why

Comment: You should probably take a look at this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/?#progress

Comment: @LisaCheng can you try this http://jsfiddle.net/f6akqq8c/2/. i updated this one. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: did it work for you @LisaCheng?

Comment: got it working!! thank you @Sushil for your help

Comment: Thanks @LisaCheng. let me post this as a solution. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: @LisaCheng i've posted my answer. please accept it and upvote it if it helped you. also sent u a request on LinkedIn.

Comment: @LisaCheng can you please mark my solution as an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the div with the class `funded-label` inside the container if you want it to be at the bottom of the container. give it an `absolute` position.

here's the updated **HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="banner-buynow">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 object-non-visible"
        data-animation-effect="fadeIn">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=
            "opentac();">Buy Now<br>

            <div class="ratebtc"></div></a>
        </div>
            <br/>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar active progress-bar-striped active">
                <div class="percentage-label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class=
        "progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active"
        style="width:1%">
            <div class="goal-label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="funded-label"></div>        
</div>
```

the **CSS** for the `funded-label` div should look like this

```
.funded-label{
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #003a74;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

and finally here' the updated **JS**

```
$(function(){
     $.getJSON("https://www2.shapeshift.io/crowdsales", function (json) {
         console.log(json);
        var soldT = Math.round(json.sold);
        var left = json.remaining;
        var total = Math.round(soldT+left);
        var ratebtc = json.rateT;
        var percent = Math.round(soldT/total*100);
        var backers = json.orders;
        var raised = Math.round(json.raised);
        var raisedtotal = raised + ' BTC';
        var goal = Math.round((raised/730) * 100);
         console.log(goal);
        var percentsold = Math.round(percent) + '%';
        var backers = json.orders + ' backers';
        var funded = Math.round(raised/730*100);
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentsold);
         console.log(soldT);
         console.log(total);
        $('.percentage-label').html(soldT + "  coins sold ");
        $('.ratebtc').html(ratebtc );  
        $('.backers').html(raisedtotal + " from " + backers );
        $('.progress-bar-success').css('width', goal + '%');
        $('.goal-label').html(raisedtotal + " towards goal of 730 BTC");
        $('.funded-label').html(funded + " % funded");
    }); 

});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f6akqq8c/2/)**. hope this helps.